# Pasar un JTable pero todos los datos en Numeros

Tags: java, mysql, excel

Tengo un sistema el cual genera un archivo excel desde un JTable, hasta el momento todo bien el detalle se presenta cuando visualizo el archivo excel, en el archivo excel tengo que convertir todos los numeros a numeros, no se si me explico se pasan como si fueran strings, utilizo una libreria llamada Apache POI para generar el archivo excel. Les dejo mi ciclo el cual recorre la tabla y la pasa a Excel:

```
for (int m = 0; m < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); m++) {
                //creamos la fila y se va incrementando 
                Row row = sheet.createRow(j++); //el j++ va incrementando desde el 12 en adelante para posicionar bien mi jtable 
                //ciclo tomar datos de tabladestino y hacerles set en el archivo excel
                for (int k = 0; k < tablaDestino.getColumnCount(); k++) {
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(k);
                    if (tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k) != null) {
                        cell.setCellValue(tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k).toString());

// int datosANum = Integer.parseInt(tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k).toString());
                        //cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Me imagino que en mi .toString debo modificarlo para que se pasen como Int?, no tengo idea de como modificar mi codigo para que se pasen como numeros, lo intente como se muestra en las lineas comentadas pero no funciona, de antemano muchas gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, utilice Double.parseDouble y converti los datos de columnas en especifico, no me funcionaba Int porque el dato excedia los caracteres para Int

```
//Columna Cuenta
cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, 0).toString()));
//columna Nombres
cell1.setCellValue(tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, 1).toString());
```

Comment: No estaría demás que revises el funcionamiento de [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).